# Kubernetes - Install APOC Library to Neo4j

Tags: kubernetes, neo4j

I am attempting to install the APOC library to a Neo4j instance running within a Kubernetes cluster. The APOC plugin is install, I can see "apoc" entries available after running `CALL dbms.procedures()` all labeled as `worksOnSystem / false`. How can I enable them?

Current YAML:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: neo4j-db
  namespace: prod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: neo4j-db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: neo4j-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: neo4j
        name: neo4j
        env:
        - name: NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted
          value: apoc.\\\*
        - name: NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS
          value: \[\"apoc\"\]
        ports:
          - containerPort: 7474
            name: http
          - containerPort: 7687
            name: bolt
          - containerPort: 7473
            name: https
        volumeMounts:
        - name: neo4j-data
          mountPath: /data
        - name: neo4j-plugins
          mountPath: /plugins
      volumes:
      - name: neo4j-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: neo4j-prod-gid-pvc
      - name: neo4j-plugins
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: neo4j-prod-plugin-gid-pvc
```

Comment: Facing the same issue.. any hacks?